# protecting HTTP traffic from sniffing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security, ssl

Sorry if this question was asked, but i haven't found exact question. I have HTML form that is being submited in plaintext. I know that there is HTTPs with SSL, but i don't want to buy certificate. Is it possible in some way to encrypt form data? I am thinking about two things:

- hashing form data via javascript - in fact i only want to send password so i don't need to know its' origin value.
- RSA - not sure if it could be implemented in javascript.
  What would you suggest? Any other variants?

Comment: "but i don't want to buy certificate", Had I known a service owner would reason as you do - I would never use any service related to that person.

Comment: To do this for free you use a self signed certificate.  Perhaps someone could write an answer explaining how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever browser-side encryption you perform will require the use of an encryption key - this will be available to an attacker. So while your password will be encrypted to the casual observer, there is no extra security afforded against a targeted attack.

Hashing is useless in this context because the hashed version of the password becomes the password used to authorise/register the user.

The only solution to this problem is an SSL certificate - they are remarkably cheap!

http://en.gandi.net/ssl/grid (no affiliate link)

You could even use a [self-signed certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) (if you can educate your users to trust the browser warning that will appear). As self-signed certs don't have a "certificate authority" to certify that the certificate was legitimately procured (and not, for example, presented by a remote host in a [man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)) browsers (and users) are pretty vociferous in their dismissal of them as "insecure".

There is a good article on Javascript Security at [Matasano Security](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/):

> Secure delivery of Javascript to browsers is a chicken-egg problem.
>
> Browser Javascript is hostile to cryptography.
>
> The "view-source" transparency of Javascript is illusory.
>
> Until those problems are fixed, Javascript isn't a serious crypto
>   research environment, and suffers for it.

Comment: what about RSA? or that is impossible to implement in javascript?

Comment: @seeker it's not impossible, but it's fatally flawed. See update

Answer (score 2):

- Hashing is a one way process.. you cannot find the original value
  from a hash.
- There is a [blowfish encryption library for
  javascript](http://dren.ch/js_blowfish/) but i don't really see the purpose in that since (like Andy stated in his answer) the key you use for encryption will be available in the plaintext that is sent to the client.

The standard (and btw only) way to do this is https. You can just use your own certificate to enable ssl, no need to buy one. But.. browsers might warn the visitor that the certificate has not been signed by a known authority.